# Python seaborn.heatmap define categories manually

Tags: python, colors, seaborn, heatmap

I am currently working on a project where I have to plot a heatmap and need to set the categories for the color coding manually to 3 fixed values (below 4->yellow, between 4 and 5-> orange, above 5-> red). How can I do it? This is a minimal working example

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns; sns.set()
m=[[4.09411765, 5.09411765, 6.09411765],[3.09411765, 4.09411765, 5.09411765], [2.09411765, 3.09411765, 4.09411765]]
m=np.matrix(m)
sns.heatmap(m,  annot=True)
plt.show()
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a [ListedColormap](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap.html#matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap). Optionally the colorbar can be drawn with extent arrows.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns; sns.set()

m = np.matrix([[4.09411765, 5.09411765, 6.09411765],
               [3.09411765, 4.09411765, 5.09411765],
               [2.09411765, 3.09411765, 4.09411765]])
sns.heatmap(m, annot=True, cmap=ListedColormap(['yellow', 'orange', 'r']), vmin=3, vmax=6,
            cbar_kws={'ticks': [4, 5], 'extend': 'both'})
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]

Comment: I have another question. Unfortunately, I had to modify your code slightly (below 3->yellow, between 3 and 5-> orange, above 5-> red). Now it seems to change the color coding between the different plots: '''        sns.heatmap(m,  annot=True, ax=ax, linewidths=.3, cmap=ListedColormap(['yellow', 'orange', 'r']), vmin=2, vmax=6,cbar_kws={'ticks': [3, 5], 'extend': 'both'})
'''

Comment: Use `..., vmin=1, vmax=7,  cbar_kws={'ticks': [3, 5], 'extend': 'both'})`. The `ListedColormap` creates equally sized regions.  Alternatively, you could double the orange: `..., cmap=ListedColormap(['yellow', 'orange', 'orange', 'r']), vmin=2, vmax=6,
            cbar_kws={'ticks': [3, 5], 'extend': 'both'})`

Comment: Thank you very much. I solved it differently: I create a new array with the categorisation (0,1,2) and then use np.imshow for the colouring and plot the text on it. With this it is easier to use a loop with different matrices. :)

Comment: You also could try `tick1 = 3; tick2 = 5` and `..., cmap=ListedColormap(['yellow', 'orange', 'orange', 'r']), vmin=2*tick1-tick2, vmax=2*tick2-tick1, cbar_kws={'ticks': [tick1, tick2], 'extend': 'both'})`